# Symfony - Form clears data from other row after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have two separate forms. One to change username, and second to change login. When i submit one of them, the second clears my data in database. It seems that they are connected, but i don't know how.

My controller

```
  $user = $this->getUser();

        $uform = $this->createForm('MainBundle\Form\UsernameType', $user);
        $uform->handleRequest($request);

        $jform = $this->createForm('MainBundle\Form\JloginType', $user);
        $jform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($uform->isSubmitted() && $uform->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        } elseif ($jform->isSubmitted() && $jform->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        }
```

Forms

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('jLogin');
}

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('username');
}
```

Widgets

```
{{ form_start(jform, { 'action': path('home_page'), 'attr': { 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit cbp-mc-form' } }) }}
<div>
    {{ form_label(jform.jLogin, 'New username') }}
    {{ form_widget(jform.jLogin) }}
</div>
<div>
    <input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Confirm'|trans }}"/>
</div>
{{ form_end(jform) }}

{{ form_start(uform, { 'action': path('home_page'), 'attr': { 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit cbp-mc-form' } }) }}
<div>
    {{ form_label(uform.username, 'New username') }}
    {{ form_widget(uform.username) }}
</div>
<div>
    <input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Confirm'|trans }}"/>
</div>
{{ form_end(uform) }}
```

Database query when i change login

```
UPDATE fos_user SET username = ?, username_canonical = ?, jLogin = ? WHERE id = ?

Parameters: [0 => null, 1 => null, 2 => jlogin, 3 => 5]
```

How to insert into database only one data from submitted form?

Comment: what's the value of these user fields after handling request?

Comment: This does not answer the exact technical issue, but I'm wondering if you've over-engineered this in the first place. Why not have a single form and process the submission based upon the state of the fields, instead of relying on which of the multiple forms was used?